# Want to wait a period of time before i check CLLocationManager's Speed again?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am currently checking the speed of my device in the delegate function `locationManager:didUpdateLocations`. On an event happening i want to wait 10 seconds and then check the speed of my device again, but i don't want my app to be suspended during those ten seconds i want my device to still be updating its speed so when i check its speed again after 10 seconds it is actually its speed after 10 seconds. Not just the speed right before i started to wait for the 10 seconds. Anyone know how i should go about doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

[image]

Your speed is being updated and then when you log it in 10 seconds it takes the current value that is stored in in the `self.currentLocation`.

So in my case the 10 second delay works on tap:

```
- (void)locationManager:(nonnull CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(nonnull NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations {

    NSLog(@"current speed: %f", locations[0].speed);
    CLLocation *location = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
    self.currentLocation = location;
}
```

Gesture recognizer:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *logoTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(logoTapped:)];
```

And the event handler:

```
- (void)logoTapped:(id)sender {

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(10 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"SPEED AFTER 10 SECONDS OF WAIT: %f", self.currentLocation.speed);
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: i posted this before i looked at your answer i was going to remove my other question because i thought it was worded poorly. But your line where it says `SPEED AFTER 10 SECONDS OF WAIT: 33. 3100` is that supposed to be the speed of the device after 10 seconds?

Comment: Yes it is speed of the device (iPhone) after 10 seconds of wait (after I tapped a button).

Comment: well then I'm going to have to say its wrong. You are having the same problem i am having. the current speed before wait is 33.3100 and the speed after wait of 10 seconds is also 33.3100 ? i doubt they are exactly the when no other two speeds are the same in your entire list. I don't think it is updating your speed while you are "waiting" and when you come out of the wait it just returns the last value of speed it had before it starts updating again. unless I'm just not understanding how its working correctly

Comment: Speed before I pushed the button was 32.2, then 10 seconds later the current speed became 33.31 and logged you that (the current speed of the device after 10 seconds)

Comment: oh i see. i was looking at it wrong. i will give that a try right now see if it fixes my problem but I'm going to have to try something other than a tap to start my wait it won't work with what I'm doing. ill try it with another method call

Comment: You can use any other event to start the wait, tap is just for the sake of example